# Understanding why Regex not matching

Tags: c#, regex

I got a regex that is not matching in C#.

```
string auth = @"oauth_consumer_key=""0685bd9184jfhq22""";
string pattern = "oauth_consumer_key=\"(\\d+)%";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(auth, pattern);
```

I always get 0 matches. I am trying to extract 0685bd9184jfhq22 string from the auth string.

Comment: You haven't actually stated what you want to do so who are we to judge if you're wrong or right?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @spender thanks for pointing out. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the whole `auth`string, try this:

```
string auth = @"oauth_consumer_key=""0685bd9184jfhq22""";
string pattern = "oauth_consumer_key=\"(.*)\"";
var match = Regex.Match(auth, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

If you want to extract the `0685bd9184jfhq22` value, just replace the `pattern` with:

```
string pattern = "(?<=oauth_consumer_key=\")(.*)(?=\")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `\d` in there, which only matches digits, and you've got letters in your value.

The expression for the key itself is probably going to be `[0-9a-z]` instead of `\d`.

You're missing the closing quote in your regex - you've got a percent sign in there where the quote should be.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"oauth_consumer_key=\"(.+)\""
```

And to get the result:

```
matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```